# How export echarts to excel?

Tags: excel, echarts

Im trying to export a graph echarts to excel, right now i can export it to png but i dont find the way to make it to excel, i will put part of my code so maybe anyone have an idea:

API: https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#echarts

I tried printing the data of the array but no way

```
saveAsImageChart(chart) {
    const url = chart.getConnectedDataURL({
      pixelRatio: 2,
      type: 'png',
      name: this.pregunta.cod + '.png',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      excludeComponents: ['toolbox'],
    });

    const deviceInfo = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();

    const $a = document.createElement('a');
    $a.download = this.pregunta.cod + '.png';
    $a.target = '_blank';
    $a.href = url;
    // Chrome and Firefox
    if (deviceInfo.browser !== 'ie') 
    {
      const evt = new MouseEvent('click', {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: false
      });
      $a.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } 

    else 
    {
      const html = '<body style="margin:0;">' +
                     '<img src="' + url + '" style="max-width:100%;" title="chart.png" />' +
                   '</body>';
      const tab = window.open();
      tab.document.write(html);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in the official GitHub repo discussions, ECharts is not able to export its charts into Excel format yet. Both environments are complex and way too different, it might not be possible to have that functionality soon.

Someone already requested it on Nov. 2016, but one of the devs closed it: [see here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/4490)

You can still ask again to see if they're ready to implement it today. It's been almost 3 years, maybe they are able to do it now?

Comment: Thanks, i think is not ready yet, what i will make is use phpexcel library and look on the echart array the data and extract it to my excel, is the only way i see i can make something similar.